# window object event for React component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a video chat application written in React. If someone close the browser tab or navigate to another page other end's participant should know that the participant disconnected.

We tried to put that disconnect function inside the unmount event with `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("cleaned up");
 theRoom.disconnect();

    };
  }, []);
```

Unfortunately for some reason, `theRoom` is `undefined` in this function.

So I tried this alternatively

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
```

console.log('***')
theRoom.disconnect();
});

This doesn't even come to the `console.log`. Can I put a native DOM event listener to track this unmount event?

Hope my question is clear to you.

Any help!

Thanks in advance. =)